# EMR UI shows the job is still running but Yarn shows the job is completed and this happening intermittently

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

After a spark job completion(spark job is able to upload the files to S3 successfully), Yarn shows the job is completed in Yarn UI, but the EMR shows the step is still running (in AWS EMR console) and it is running like
forever.

This happening intermittently: sometimes as soon as the job completes Yarn and EMR both show the job is completed.

Any thoughts on this ?

I am using:

- spring-boot: 2.4.9
- spark-core_2.12: 3.1.2
- spark-sql_2.12: 3.1.2
- Hadoop-client: 3.2.0

Comment: EMR checks job status from the yarn itself so there must be some lag. Can you please tell me the exact lag you are facing and what is the accepted lag from your side?

Comment: @ankushsingh10000 We are not expecting any lag between yarn,EMR checks job status…as soon as yarn completed,we are expecting EMR job status should be in completed status(in the Aws console)…earlier it was working fine, recently we upgraded spring boot,spark core ,spark sql and Hadoop versions….not sure what causes this lag